# Check successful loading of pixel image in svg

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg

Using javascript, I am adding many pixel images, by moving `<image id="myimage" xlink:href="mysource.png" ... />` elements from an `XMLdoc` to the DOM of an SVG image in a loop, like so

```
var elems = this.XMLdoc.getElementsByTagName('image');
var elem = elems.item(0);
svg.appendChild(elem);
```

Sometimes not all of the images are completely loaded, due to network problems, or server limitations.
After loading all images, I would like to check whether that has been successful and, if not, reload the pixel image `mysource.png`.

I could remove and add back all `<image>` tags and rely on that the cached images are loaded successfully, but then I would still not know if all images were loaded in the second round.

If it was included with `<img>` in html, I would do this by checking `image.complete`, but that does not seem to work for the SVG images.

I am also using Snap.svg to manipulate the SVG. A solution based on this library would be convenient if it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SVG you listen to the load event through the `load` event, you can do it like this:

```
var elems = this.XMLdoc.getElementsByTagName('image');
var elem = elems.item(0);
elem.addEventListener("error", replaceImage);
svg.appendChild(elem);

function replaceImage(e){
   var parent = this.parentNode;
   var newImage = this.cloneNode();
   newImage.addEventListener("error", replaceImage);
   parent.removeChild(this);
   parent.appendChild(newImage);
}
```

Comment: Ok, assuming Snap.svg does not interfere, you would build an array of all elements and remove them, one by one, once their load event triggered? Remember, that I need to know the elements which did not load!

Comment: Both seems to work with chrome. Is there a clever way to update an SVG image such that it would try to load the pixel graphic again (other than changing the source or removing the tag and adding it back)?

Comment: Listening to `error` should work. You usually don't do this kind of error checking, but if you are concerned simply add `alert("there was a problem loading an image, please reload the page)` on the error callback.

Comment: That's unfortunately not a solution. There are hundreds of thumbnail images in the svg. Mainly due to restrictive rules of the server, but also because of network issues, many of them are not loaded immediately. The user would need to reload a dozen times util he has them all.

Comment: I have changed my answer, it should serve you only as a guidance, as these kind of conditions are difficult to replicate. Say there's a network issue, it would loop endlessly.